# What's the most appropriate folder layout for a react frontend?

Tags: reactjs, npm

Recently, I've taken an interest in React as I believe  that it'll allow me to hopefully get a job in the near future. I already know Laravel PHP fairly well but that doesn't seem to cut it when it comes to looking for jobs.
I've so far, managed to make a single page twitter clone an I will hopefully be using firebase to store and return tweets.
I would also like to add multiple pages and perhaps some sort of authentication system.
However, in order to do that, I need to do utilize react's router.
My current folder setup looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxqo6.png).

For an app that only has one page this works well, however, I am unsure as to how it would work with multiple pages and how I should lay that out.
For example, should I have a folder called, pages? Then have a folder for each page an then within those pages, the Page.js component and then a components folder for that page? That's my current thinking but I am totally clueless on the best way to deal with this.
I think it would be cool if i could have one big folder which stores all components so that I can reuse them whenever I want.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: React is unopinionated regarding folder structure. Check their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html). Since this doesn't have a correct answer, it doesn't belong in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to creating a "good" react app is abstraction. If a component is doing two things, break it down into two components. The idea here is that you will start to notice redundancies in your components where you can turn similar components into a single component used multiple times. This is also why thoroughly planning out your application beforehand is best.

With all this in mind it is best practice to have a dedicated "Components" folder in the "src" folder. At the top level this will contain commonly reused UI components (lists, modals, cards, buttons, etc.). Each of these component folders is capitalized and will also store any "sub-components." An example of a sub-component would be a drop-down menu component within a header component. Each components folder will look something like this:

```
components
|  Header
|  |  DropDownMenu
|  |  |  index.js
|  |  |  style.css
|  |  NavButton
|  |  |  index.js
|  |  |  style.css
|  |  index.js
|  |  style.css
```

In addition to a components, create folders for groups of higher level attributes or libraries; for example a "pages" or "routes" folder which houses the apps different pages. Another good example is a separate folder for Redux to manage actions, reducers, and storage... or maybe a media folder for local images and svgs.

Here is a simple template for a small react app's folder structure:

```
src
|  firebase
|  |  firebaseConfig.js
|  components
|  |  Component
|  |  |  SubComponent
|  |  |  |  index.js
|  |  |  |  style.css
|  |  |  index.js
|  |  |  style.css
|  media
|  |  images
|  |  |  image.png
|  |  svgs
|  |  |  image.svg
|  pages
|  |  Home.js
|  redux
|  |  actions
|  |  |  action.js
|  |  reducers
|  |  |  reducer.js
|  |  store.js
|  |  types.js
|  App.css
|  App.js
|  index.css
|  index.css
```

Comment: Ah, right I see. So rather than it being orentaited around the pages, the pages just sort of exist along side the components.